# Is the std::array bit compatible with the old C array?

Tags: c++, c++11, memcpy, reinterpret-cast

Is the underlying *bit representation* for an `std::array<T,N> v` and a `T u[N]` the same?

In other words, is it safe to copy `N*sizeof(T)` bytes from one to the other? (Either through `reinterpret_cast` or `memcpy`.)

**Edit:**

For clarification, the emphasis is on *same bit representation* and `reinterpret_cast`.

For example, let's suppose I have these two classes over some trivially copyable type `T`, for some `N`:

```
struct VecNew {
    std::array<T,N> v;
};

struct VecOld {
    T v[N];
};
```

And there is the legacy function

```
T foo(const VecOld& x);
```

If the representations are the same, then this call is safe and avoids copying:

```
VecNew x;
foo(reinterpret_cast<const VecOld&>(x));
```

Comment: Are you doing the copy using `data`/`&array_name[0]` or using the name of the "array" itself?

Comment: Not through `reinterpret_cast`, because of strict aliasing.

Comment: Hmm... the original question was about copying, the new question is about `reinterpret_cast`-ing. That's somewhat different...

Comment: @Barry, the original question was "Is the std::array bit compatible with the old C array?", and still is. Everything else is a consequence of that.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to modernize legacy C++ code by replacing old constructs by new ones, right?

Comment: Then somebody changes `VecNew` by adding new field for example and enjoy debugging. No, thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I say yes (but the standard does not guarantee it).

According to [array]/2:

> An array is an *aggregate* ([[dcl.init.aggr](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr)]) that can be
>   list-initialized with up to N elements whose types are convertible to
>   T.

And [dcl.init.aggr]:

> An *aggregate* is an array or a class (Clause [class]) with
>
> - no user-provided, explicit, or inherited constructors ([class.ctor]),
> - no private or protected non-static data members (Clause
>     [class.access]),
> - no virtual functions ([class.virtual]), and
> - no virtual, private, or protected base classes ([class.mi]).

In light of this, *"can be list-initialized"* is only possible if there are no other members in the beginning of the class and no vtable.

Then, `data()` is specified as:

> `constexpr T* data() noexcept;`
>   
>   *Returns*: A pointer such that `[data(), data() + size())` is a valid range, and `data() == addressof(front())`.

The standard basically wants to say "it returns an array" but leaves the door open for other implementations.

The only possible other implementation is a structure with individual elements, in which case you *can* run into aliasing problems. But in my view this approach does not add anything but complexity. There is nothing to gain by unrolling an array into a struct.

So it makes **no sense** *not* to implement `std::array` as an array.

But a loophole does exist.

Comment: I disagree that aliasing problems could occur. What is your reasoning for that claim?

Comment: A structure  and an array are incompatible types in terms of strict aliasing.

Comment: I don't think your interpretation of the strict aliasing rule is correct. If that were the case, then an array type would also be incompatible with its element type, which is clearly absurd.

Comment: His assertion on strict aliasing does not imply what you claim it does.

Comment: @Brian That's not what RustyX was saying. An array has never been compatible with a `struct` having the same number of same-typed members. However, even your tangential inference about the compatibility of pointers to arrays versus pointers to their elements is soon to be all too true! See ecatmur's answer regarding the fun in store from the in-drafting P0137R1. And please, if you are so inclined and in a position to, file a National Body comment expressing scepticism of it.

Answer (score 20):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but you should simply use [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):

```
T c[N];
std::array<T, N> cpp;

// from C to C++
std::copy(std::begin(c), std::end(c), std::begin(cpp));

// from C++ to C
std::copy(std::begin(cpp), std::end(cpp), std::begin(c));
```

If `T` is a trivially copyable type, this'll compile down to `memcpy`. If it's not, then this'll do element-wise copy assignment and be correct. Either way, this does the Right Thing and is quite readable. No manual byte arithmetic necessary.

Comment: nitpick: `std::copy` doesn't always compile down to `memcpy` it's an implementation detail. For example VC++ uses `memmove` for byte copies.

Comment: I'm torn. This is a great answer... for a different question!

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/SGdWwp Looks like it is doing the fast copy only if the two arguments are of the same array type(only `test` and `test3` compile to `memmove`).

Answer (score 16):

`std::array` provides method [data()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/data) which can be used to copy to/from c-style array of proper size:

```
const size_t size = 123;
int carray[size];
std::array<int,size> array;

memcpy( carray, array.data(), sizeof(int) * size );
memcpy( array.data(), carray, sizeof(int) * size );
```

As stated on [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

> This container is an aggregate type with the same semantics as a struct holding a C-style array T[N] as its only non-static data member.

so it seems that memory footprint would be compatible with c-style array, though it is not clear why you want to use "hacks" with `reinterpret_cast` when there is a proper way which does not have any overhead.

Comment: It is exactly the "so it seems" part that I'd like to get clarified.

Comment: you did not answer why

Answer (score 9):

The requirement on the `data()` method is that it return a pointer `T*` such that:

> `[data(), data() + size())` is a valid range, and `data() == addressof(front())`.

This implies that you can access each element sequentially via the `data()` pointer, and so if `T` is trivially copyable you can indeed use `memcpy` to copy `sizeof(T) * size()` bytes to/from an array `T[size()]`, since this is equivalent to `memcpy`ing each element individually.

However, you cannot use `reinterpret_cast`, since that would violate strict aliasing, as `data()` is not required to *actually* be backed by an array - and also, even if you were to guarantee that `std::array` contains an array, since C++17 you cannot (even using `reinterpret_cast`) cast a pointer to an array to/from a pointer to its first member (you have to use `std::launder`).

Comment: "as data() is not required to actually be backed by an array", uhm, that's nonsense.

Comment: Re " since C++17 you cannot (even using reinterpret_cast) cast a pointer to an array to/from a pointer to its first member (you have to use std::launder)", that sounds interesting: the committee going lunatically berserk! More info please. In the meantime I'll make some popcorn.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf "not required to actually be backed by an array" - trivially true for N=0 and N=1; implementable via vendor-library cooperation for N>1.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf "a pointer to an array cannot be cast to/from a pointer to its first element": see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0137r1.html

Comment: Not the N=1; a variable is an array of size 1.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf "for purposes of pointer arithmetic and comparison"; not for all purposes and certainly not as far as aliasing goes.

Comment: Uhm, re the link, that's a wall of text. Several hundred kilometers of it. Can you sort of vaguely indicate a region of, say, less than 203 meters?

Comment: re the "certainly not", that's nonsense.

Comment: It seems this is about giving a compiler vendor a controlling interest in the management of the standard, whence, that compiler's shortcomings and silly behaviors become standardized. Oh well.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf the edits and additions to [basic.compound]/3 are the really fun bit. Note that I linked the wrong version initially; you should be reading P0137r1.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf nonsense maybe, but that's the direction the Standard is going: `int a; int (&r)[1] = reinterpret_cast<int(&)[1]>(a); r[0] = 42;` is now UB. Truly we live in interesting times.

Comment: Do you know if the persons doing this work have given any rationale for the, uh, changes? Like what they hope to achieve?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf to my understanding they're formalising what compilers are already doing while making it possible to implement containers that create and destroy objects (esp. vector and optional). The intent is presumably to be able to squeeze every last drop of UB out of the aliasing rules to perform better on SPEC (ahem: on user code).

Comment: Why on Earth did the authors, right after specifically allowing for conversion between pointers to a standard-layout struct vs its 1st member, then tack on - _in a friggin' Note_, as if a passing afterthought - that the same allowance does not hold for an array and its 1st element? Is there a nuance I'm missing where one should be allowed but the second not? Surely `( (NonexistentStruct*)somePointer )->nonexistentMember` is not any less dangerous than `( (NonexistentArray[42]*)somePointer )[23]`? ...or whatever the syntax; I don't do this stuff, ofc. What's the crucial distinction I'm missing?

Comment: I bet a lot of libboost's hacks are gonna break now.

Comment: @underscore_d it's not about danger, it's about optimization; a lot of scientific code (*cough* SPEC *cough*) can be effectively accelerated if the compiler assumes that different-sized arrays and pointers don't alias even when the element type is the same. The speed-ups this yields are considered (by compiler authors, and, being fair, to their customers writing scientific, Fortran-style code) to be worth the potential confusion and breakage to their users writing more systems- or object-oriented code.

Comment: @ecatmur Just `optional`. `vector` is still formally broken. In particular, `vector::data` is unimplementable in standard C++.

Comment: @T.C. Can you link to a discussion of the problem with `vector`?

Answer (score 7):

`array` doesn't mandate much about the underlying type over which you instantiate it.

To have *any* possibility of useful results from using `memcpy` or `reinterpret_cast` to do a copy, the type you instantiated it over would have to be trivially copyable. Storing those items in an `array` doesn't affect the requirement that `memcpy` (and such) only work with trivially copyable types.

`array` is required to be a *contiguous container* and an aggregate, which pretty much means that the storage for the elements must be an array. The standard shows it as:

```
T elems[N]; // exposition only
```

It later, however, has a note that at least implies that it's being an array is required (§[array.overview]/4):

> [Note: The member variable `elems` is shown for exposition only, to emphasize that `array` is a class aggregate.
>   **The name `elems` is not part of array’s interface.** —end note]

[emphasis added]

Note how it's really only the specific name `elems` that isn't required.

Comment: The [new draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/array) got rid of that part. Now we just have that it's an aggregate that can be list initialized with `N` `T`s (but +1).

Comment: @Barry: I'm not at all sure that really changes much. Offhand, I don't see a way of meeting its requirements (contiguous container, aggregate) except by having only one data member, which is an array. I suppose if you could assure against padding between elements, you *could* create a variadic template of discrete elements, but only because the elements would still be addressable like an array.

Comment: The initialization couldn't work if `array` wasn't a simple `struct` wrapper of a raw array.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Oh I'm not saying `std::array` isn't definitely a wrapper around a raw array. I'm just saying that now the wording around that description is totally different (not sure what the significance of that chance is tbh. just pointing it out).

Comment: The initialization (but not other parts)could work if the storage were discrete members in the correct order.

Comment: I mean, the `data` functionality only guarantees that there is effectively an array in there. The initialization means that there's nothing before that array. So there is an array, and there's nothing before it, and so as the first member of a struct a pointer to it can be reinterpreted as pointer to the struct and vice versa (this is at the end of the section about class members).

Comment: @JerryCoffin "(but not other parts)" yeah, like basic indexing and pointer arithmetic!