# How *(&arr + 1) - arr is working to give the array size

Tags: c++, arrays

```
int arr[] = { 3, 5, 9, 2, 8, 10, 11 };      
int arrSize = *(&arr + 1) - arr;
std::cout << arrSize;
```

I am not able to get how this is working. So anyone can help me with this.

Comment: I believe whether this is allowed or not is a grey zone, though it gives the expected result on basically every implementation.

Comment: You could remove the `val` declaration, as it has nothing to do with the question nor the functionality.

Comment: This is not a usual idiom. Other readers of the code will be confused as well. Sure, it's a clever trick. Avoid cleverness like the plague.

Comment: Can you copy this into a `main` function, then post the assembly language generated by the compiler?  *The truth is in the assembly language* :-)

Comment: Just use [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I was curious, but I dont think we can learn much from this: https://godbolt.org/z/YdWh8h8YY

Comment: turns out that Why does this yield correct result? and Why does it *work*? are quite different questions in this case =)

Comment: And if you -O1 that, you get the very informative `mov eax, 7; ret`

Comment: This is the same question but for C: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56154380/1896169
The C and C++ standards are sufficiently different, however, that it makes sense to have separate questions

Comment: FWIW, another alternative is `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])`, IIRC.

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61237796/how-does-arr-1-arr-give-the-length-in-elements-of-array-arr

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If we "draw" the array together with the pointers, it will look something like this:

```
+--------+--------+-----+--------+-----+
| arr[0] | arr[1] | ... | arr[6] | ... |
+--------+--------+-----+--------+-----+
^        ^                       ^
|        |                       |
&arr[0]  &arr[1]                 |
|                                |
&arr                             &arr + 1
```

The type of the expressions `&arr` and `&arr + 1` is `int (*)[7]`. If we dereference either of those pointers, we get a value of type `int[7]`, and as with all arrays, it will decay to a pointer to its first element.

So what's happening is that we take the difference between a pointer to the first element of `&arr + 1` (the dereference really makes this UB, but will still work with any sane compiler) and a pointer to the first element of `&arr`.

All pointer arithmetic is done in the base-unit of the pointed-to type, which in this case is `int`, so the result is the number of `int` elements between the two addresses being pointed at.

---

It might be useful to know that an array will naturally decay to a pointer to its first element, ie the expression `arr` will decay to `&arr[0]`, which will have the type `int *`.

Also, for any pointer (or array) `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`. So `*(&arr + 1)` is really the same as `(&arr)[1]` (which makes the UB much more visible).

Comment: Pardon my naivety, but doesn't dereferencing have a higher precedence than subtraction?  My understanding of your answer doesn't account for the dereferencing before the subtraction.

Comment: For example, the expression `&arr + 1` is evaluated first into an address.  Next, that address is dereferenced to an integer (i.e. memory is read).  Then the address of the array is subtracted from the value read from memory.  Am I wrong here?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The dereference in `*(&arr + 1)` will make the expression into the type `int[7]` which will then decay to `int *`, which is the same type a `arr` used in the subtraction (remember that `arr` is the same as `&arr[0]`).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yes, dereference will happen first. Without it, the subtraction wouldn't be possible because the pointers would have unrelated types (`int (*)[7]` and `int *`). Dereferencing `(&arr + 1)` produces a value of type `int [7]`, which then decays to `int *`, making the pointer types the same. The dereference here merely changes the pointer type, and not its numerical value.

Comment: @Thomas `&arr + 1` is of type `int (*)[7]`. A dereference there will give you an `int[7]`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @scohe001 Which at that moment gives you a non-existent object and therefore UB.  Strictly speaking it doesn't matter that the array is then immediately converted to a pointer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude will dereferencing make it `int(&)[7]` or `int[7]`? https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rss83MvnG

Comment: @dbush Whether or not this is actually UB seems to be undecided, there is an active language defect related to this. I've specifically asked that question : [Dereferencing one past the end pointer to array type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52727045/dereferencing-one-past-the-end-pointer-to-array-type).

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili The type of `&arr` (and `&arr + 1`) is `int (*)[7]`. The type of `*(&arr)` (and `*(&arr + 1)`) is `int[7]`. And `int[7]` decays to `int *`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude why does the static assert fail in the link I shared then?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Remember that expressions can't have reference types. http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-1 And `decltype` adds fake `&` and `&&` to types of expressions to indicate value categories of those expressions (for lvalues and xvalues respectively; types of prvalues are unchanged).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I certainly didn't know that. If `a` in `int &&a = 1;` is an l-value (r-value references themselves are l-values), why is `decltype(a)` == `int&&` then?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili `decltype` has special rules for variables. For them it returns the type that's written next to them. If you do `decltype((a))`, it will return `int &` (because unlike `a`, `decltype` doesn't consider `(a)` a variable, so the regular rules apply).

Comment: Very interesting. It's very complex. All I want is something like `decl_decay_t` which acts like `std::decay_t<decltype(exp)>` so I can do `decl_decay_t(a)::value_type` and alike. Maybe I'll add a macro...

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Precedence only controls the grouping of operators with operands - it does not control the order in which expressions are evaluated.  It only means the expression is *parsed* as `(*(&arr + 1)) - (arr)` as opposed to `*((&arr + 1) - arr)` or something else.  Yes, the result of `*(&arr + 1)` must be known before you can subtract the result of `arr` from it, otherwise the expression doesn't make sense.  That's not due to the precedence of the `*` vs. `-` operators, though.

Answer (score 19):

That program has undefined behaviour. `(&arr + 1)` is a valid pointer that points "one beyond" `arr`, and has type `int(*)[7]`, however it doesn't point to an `int [7]`, so dereferencing it is invalid.

It so happens that your implementation assumes there is a second `int [7]` after the one you declare, and subtracts the location of the first element of that array that exists from the location of the first element of the fictitious array that the pointer arithmetic invented.

Comment: How does the dereferencing help in calculating the size, since dereferencing has higher priority than subtraction and the dereferencing can be Undefined Behavior?

Comment: I'm not sure this is definitely UB. I asked a related question ([Dereferencing one past the end pointer to array type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52727045/dereferencing-one-past-the-end-pointer-to-array-type)) and the answer to "is it legal" seems to be "it's an active core language issue". Edit : it still shouldn't be used, as it is also not definitely allowed yet.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews that's why I talk about a fictitious `int[7]`. It's UB, the implementation can do anything, here it chooses to assume an extra array. Or it isn't UB, and the standard requires the assumption of another `int[7]` for the purpose of the subtraction

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux clang thinks it's UB, GCC and MSVC think it's not https://godbolt.org/z/r4e14e9MG

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: clang doesn't accept it as `constexpr`, but compiles it ok with `return ...`.  https://godbolt.org/z/r96YhWEe1 - With `-fsanitize=undefined`, clang makes asm that checks if the stack pointer is within 28 bytes of the top of virtual address space, so it's checking for pointer overflow.  (It of course runs fine).  That may be a sign that it doesn't "understand" / "accept" what's going on; it just wrote that memory so the pointer's definitely valid if it didn't crash.  So probably it doesn't realize that it's just doing 1-past-end of a valid object.

Comment: @PeterCordes Interesting analysis. The standard requires compilers to check for undefined behavior in constexpr. I used constexpr there to "get compilers' opinions" so to speak :)

Comment: @PeterCordes I *think* the expression `(&arr + 1)` is a valid 1-past end pointer (address of the hypothetical next array);  the apparent dereferencing of that isn't actually reading any memory location - it is just (effectively) changing the same value to a different pointer type (address of the hypothetical first *element* of that hypothetical array). Aren't the address of an array and the address of its first element the same *by definition*?

Comment: No +1 as you lack an explanation *why* it's UB.  I, too, think that it's UB however: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39401136/1116364

Answer (score 10):

You need to explore what the type of the `&arr` expression is, and how that affects the `+ 1` operation on it.

Pointer arithmetic works in 'raw units' of the pointed-to type; `&arr` is the **address of your array**, so it points to an object of type, "array of 7 int". Adding `1` to that pointer actually adds *the size of the type* to the address – so `7 * sizeof(int)` is added to the address.

However, in the *outer* expression (subtraction of `arr`), the operands are pointers to `int` objects<sup>1</sup> (not arrays), so the 'units' are just `sizeof(int)` – which is 7 times smaller than in the *inner* expression. Thus, the subtraction results in the size of the array.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is because, in such expressions, an array variable (such as the *second* operand, `arr`) decays to a pointer to its first element; further, your *first* operand is also an array, as the `*` operator dereferences the modified value of the array pointer.

---

*Note on Possible UB:* Other answers (and comments thereto) have suggested that the dereferencing operation, `*(&arr + 1)`, invokes undefined behaviour. However, looking through [this Draft C++17 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf), there is the vaguest of suggestions that it may not:

> **6.7.2 Compound Types**
> ...
> <sup>3</sup>    … For purposes of pointer arithmetic (8.5.6) and comparison
> (8.5.9, 8.5.10), a pointer past the end of the last element of an
> array x of n elements is considered to be equivalent to a pointer to a
> hypothetical element x[n].

But I won't claim "Language-Lawyer" status here, as there is no *explicit* mention in that section about dereferencing such a pointer.

Comment: Did you account for the deferencing of the expression `&arr - 1`?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Where does that expression occur in the posted code?

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  It was supposed to be `&arr + 1`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews No problem - see edit. (Thanks for suggesting, BTW.)

Comment: I won't consider that section of the standard vaguely supporting it. It clearly says "purposes of pointer arithmetic and comparison". This means that `x[n]` can be freely compared or subtracted with any other element in the array. Not more, not less.

Comment: @IS4 Indeed. But in the case of a pointer to an array, then `&arr` and `&arr[0]` are the same address ... just different pointer types.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a declaration like this

```
int arr[] = { 3, 5, 9, 2, 8, 10, 11 };
```

the  the expression `&arr + 1` will point to the memory after the last element of the array. The value of the expression is equal to the value of the expression `arr + 7` where `7` is the number of elements in the array declared above. The only difference is that the expression `&arr + 1`  has the type `int ( * )[7]` while the expression `arr + 7`   has the type `int *`.

So due to the integer arithmetic the difference `( arr + 7 ) - arr` will yield 7:  the number of elements in the array.

On the other hand, dereferencing the expression `&att + 1` having the type `int ( * )[7]` we will get lvalue of the type `int[7]` that in turn used in the expression `*(&arr + 1) - arr` is converted to a pointer of the type `int *`  and has the same value as `arr + 7` as it was pointed out above. So the expression will yield the number of elements in the array.

The only difference between these two expressions

```
( arr + 7 ) - arr
```

and

```
*( &arr + 1 ) - arr
```

is that in the first case we will need explicitly to specify the number of elements in the array to get the address of the memory after the last element of the array while in the second case the compiler itself will calculate the address of the memory after the last element of the array knowing the array declaration.

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned, `*(&arr + 1)` triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because `&arr + 1` is a pointer to one-past-the end of an array of type `int [7]` and that pointer is subsequently dereferenced.

An alternate way of doing this would be to convert the relevant pointers to `uintptr_t`, subtracting, and dividing the element size.

```
int arrSize = reinterpret_cast<int>((reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&arr + 1) -
                                     reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(arr)) / sizeof *arr);
```

Or using C-style casts:

```
int arrSize = (int)(((uintptr_t)(&arr + 1) - (uintptr_t)arr) / sizeof *arr);
```

Comment: Wouldn't `ptrdiff_t` be better here than `uintptr_t`?

Comment: @AdrianMole Only for the result type instead of `int`. I think it could overflow/underflow if you try to subtract it.

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.reinterpret.cast#5 : *"mappings between pointers and integers are otherwise implementation-defined."* so this solution can work, it likely works on most implementation, but is not portable. You very well could have an implementation where, for example `(uintptr_t)&arr[0]` is bigger than `(uintptr_t)&arr[1]`.

Answer (score -1):

This one is simple:

1. `arr` is just a pointer to the 0'th element of the array (`&arr[0]`);
2. `&arr` gives a pointer to the previous pointer;
3. `&arr+1` gives a pointer to a pointer to `arr[0]`+`sizeof(arr)*1`;
4. `*(&arr + 1)` turns the previous value into just `&arr[0]+sizeof(arr)*1`;
5. `*(&arr + 1) - arr` also subtracts the pointer to `arr[0]` leaving just `sizeof(arr)*1`.

So the only tricks here are that static arrays in C internally preserve all their static type information including their total sizes and that when you increment a pointer by some integer value, C compilers don't just add the value to it, but for whatever reason standards require to increase the pointers by the value of `sizeof()` of whatever type the pointer is assigned to times the specified value so `*(&p+idx)` gives the same result as `p[idx]`.

C language is designed to allow for very simplistic compilers so inside it is full of little tricks like this. I would not recommend using them in production code though. Remember about other developers who may need to read and maintain your code later and use the most simple and obvious stuff available instead (for the example it is obviously just using sizeof() directly).

Comment: `arr` is an array, not a pointer. Arrays can *decay* to pointers to their first elements in many cases, but this is **not** one of those cases. Consequently, `&arr`, is not a pointer-to-pointer (not `int **`), but, as 3 other answers have stated, a pointer-to-array (`int (*)[7]`).

Comment: Also step 4 is slightly confusing, since `&arr[0]+sizeof(arr)*1` would additionally multiply the rhs by `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: In C for static arrays the only difference with pointers is the fact that it has some metadata associated with it which we can ignore for all the cases except for the hidden sizeof() which always gives the total size of the array in bytes, not just the number of its elements. So I don't see any confusion here. For dynamic arrays there is absolutely no difference with pointers at all except for the syntax.

Comment: Let's ignore "dynamic arrays" for now, since it's just a name for regular pointers pointing to dynamically allocated memory. *"only difference with pointers is the fact that it has some metadata associated"* It's a way to think about arrays I guess, but this interpretation breaks under scrutiny. A (static) array is not a pointer (with or without metadata). When an array is converted to a pointer, the resulting pointer is computed on the fly, in general it's not stored in the memory otherwise.

Comment: If you use your debugger to inspect the memory associated with an array, you'll find no pointer there. Mext, if you make a pointer-to-pointer (`int **`) and try to point it to an array, the compiler won't let you - again, because arrays don't *store* pointers to their elements. *"has some metadata associated"* There's no hidden metadata involved. They just have different types compared to pointers. They are implicitly converted to pointers in many cases, but not always. That doesn't happen are applying `sizeof`, yes, but also when applying and `&` to it, or binding it to a reference.

Comment: The fact that the static array related pointers are not stored in memory and just get evaluated at compile time does not mean that they are not designed as pointers. And although `int** p = arr` does give you a warning (with gcc at least), `int* p = arr` compiles just fine without any warnings and works as expected.

Comment: It is mostly just a question of how you want to look at it but at least for me the fact that you can do `*arr` and you get the same value as `arr[0]` and `*arr+3` is the same as `arr[3]` and `(int)&arr[0]` always gives exactly the same result as `(int)arr` is a firm enough proof for the fact that in C the whole [] syntax is nothing more than some early syntax sugar and the whole array support idea was probably added as an afterthought and expecting a compiler to provide the functionality using not more than just a couple of tiny little dirty hacks to the main part of the implementation.

Comment: Just to be precise I mean `*(arr+3)` of course, not `*arr+3`. It is sad that Stack Overflow is so strict about 5 minutes to edit a comment even before any answer has arrived so I have to add an extra comment to correct the previous mistake.