# Passing std::array to a function that accepts C style array by address

Tags: c++, arrays, pass-by-reference

Let's say I have the following `std::array`

```
#define MAX_SIZE(6)
typedef struct MyStruct
{
  int test_integer;
  float test_float;
} MyStruct_T

std::array<MyStruct_T, MAX_SIZE> my_array = { 0 }
```

Now there is a function that accepts C style array by address:

```
void MyFunction(MyStruct_T const (&input)[MAX_SIZE])
```

What is the right way to pass `my_array` to `MyFunction`?

If the function declaration/definition argument cannot be changed, what is the most efficient way to convert `std::array` to C style array? (I only see C style to `std::array` methods)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the std::array bit compatible with the old C array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39376813/is-the-stdarray-bit-compatible-with-the-old-c-array)

Comment: There's no good way. The function should be rewritten to accept a pointer and a size.

Comment: If the function declaration/definition argument cannot be changed, what is the most efficient way to convert std::array to C style array? (I only see C style to std::array methods)

Comment: @coffeenator There isn't one, at least not standard conforming.  In *practice*, reinterpreting a `std::array<MyStruct_T, MAX_SIZE>&` as a `MyStruct_T[MAX_SIZE]&`, or a `std::array<MyStruct_T, MAX_SIZE>*` as a `MyStruct_T[MAX_SIZE]*`, *will likely* work, but you should not rely on that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - I'd be more inclined to do such a cast on the pointer returned by the array's `data()` member.   That said, I also wouldn't offer any guarantee that such a conversion is safe - I'd prefer rewriting `MyFunction()` to accept either a `std::array` argument, or a `MyStruct_T*` and a size.  Apart from readability (code involving casts is a bear to get right, and too many "smart" developers have a habit of subsequently "improving" or "tidying" such a cast and breaking it) there is no room for debate over potential undefined behaviour due to attempts at type punning.

Comment: If you can rewrite the function, accepting `std::span` from C++20 (or from `gsl::span` from thee gsl library if you can't use c++20) can be a better option (more general) than accepting `std::array` or a pointer and a size.

Comment: Thank you all. I ended up changing the function definition/declaration.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: `T[…]&` doesn’t parse: it’s `T(&)[…]` (and similarly for `*`).  (Perhaps you know that and it’s a typo, but it should still be given correctly here.)

Comment: I'm aware of that, I wrote it that way to make the point clearer without confusing beginners on the syntax. In this case, I would suggest making use of `using` statements to make it cleaner, eg: `using my_std_array = std::array<MyStruct_T, MAX_SIZE>; my_std_array my_array = {};` ... `using my_c_array = MyStruct_T[MAX_SIZE]; void MyFunction(const my_c_array &input)` Then you can do `MyFunction(reinterpret_cast<my_c_array&>(my_array));` or `MyFunction(*reinterpret_cast<my_c_array*>(&my_array));`